# DynamicImage from SubImage<&DynamicImage>

Tags: image, rust

Using the [image crate](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.1/image/index.html), I'm trying to crop an image and resize it without copying the whole image.

```rust
let img: DynamicImage = image.open("image.jpg").unwrap();
let square: SubImage<&DynamicImage> = image.view(0, 0, 100, 100);
let small_square = square.thumbnail(25, 25); <-- no method named `thumbnail` for type SubImage
```

How can I use [DynamicImage](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.1/image/enum.DynamicImage.html)'s methods on a [SubImage](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.1/image/struct.SubImage.html) directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a subimage to [image::imageops::thumbnail()](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.1/image/imageops/fn.thumbnail.html).

Comment: Nice! But it is weird that all imageops functions are duplicated in DynamicImage.

Comment: The `DynamicImage` versions wrap the output `ImageBuffer<>` in a new `DynamicImage`, so it keeps your code much cleaner when only working with DynamicImages.